Is it possible to prove that your criminal case in your country was illegal when obtaining a visa/permanent residency/citizenship?
I am a citizen of the Russian Federation. For a long time I have been dreaming of moving to Europe or the USA. But six months ago I was prosecuted for selling drugs.
I'll tell you right away that the case is completely falsified. I didn't even have any drugs on me. And the entire evidence base is based on some photos that were allegedly found in my phone, and one of these photos was used to find a drug that I was supposedly going to sell. The forensics even confirmed that it didn't have my fingerprints on it. There's a lot of irregularities in the case. Lawyers give a good prognosis. But, unfortunately, the judicial practice in my country is such that if the case is brought to court, they try to put a person in jail, despite the violations and weak evidence.
In this situation, apart from the term I am facing (which is about 10 years), I am also frightened by the prospect of never leaving the country, as any civilized country treats articles on drugs very seriously.
Back to the question in the title. If things don't turn out well for me, is there any way in the future that this case can be reviewed in international/European/American courts when it comes to getting a visa/permanent residency/citizenship? I'm sure any normal court would recognize this case as illegal.
It used to be possible to file a complaint with the European Court of Human Rights, but Russia withdrew from the Convention in 2022.

I would re-phrase from "civilized country" to just "most countries;" the vast majority of drug laws are forms of control, not moral enhancements to the criminal code.

When it comes to visa or citizenship, a criminal record in the home country matters if and because the host country wants it to matter. If a Western country decides to ignore a Russian criminal record, that is purely their own decision. Russia could file an interpol notice to harass you, but those are not automatic. The host country can always decide to ignore it.
So the question is not "who can cancel the record for travel purposes," but "how to convince a country to ignore the record for immigration purposes." That would depend on the country you are talking about and on the publicity of your case. Some people with Russian convictions are even exchanged for Russian assassins, but I presume you are not that well known.
Citizenship tends to come only after years of residence. If you are currently outside Russia, you can apply for political asylum where you are and use the prosecution as evidence. If the officials believe you, that becomes a powerful point in support of your asylum claim.

"Some people with Russian convictions are even exchanged for Russian assassins..." - Yes, you make a good point. It surprises me a lot, too.
As you rightly point out, I'm not that famous. The article is not political, and not politically motivated. But unfortunately, in my country, you don't have to be in opposition to the government to be in the wrong place at the wrong time.
Well, the only thing left to do is to fight to the end. Everything is at stake. Thank you very much for your reply!

There are visa-free destinations for Russians, and others where a criminal record is not an automatic disqualification for a visa.

Yes, I understand. But unfortunately, the countries I'm interested in require a visa, and a criminal record certificate))

@ErzaMoksha, do you want to get out now, or do you want to pick and choose? From news reports, people facing the Russian legal system are pressured into signing military contracts.

@Erza Moksha — The gut feeling seems to suggest to flee first to anywhere you can flee to, and only think about permanent wishes later.

@o-m, At this point, I don't plan on going anywhere. First of all, there are no opportunities. Secondly, as I said, although the case is trumped up, it is not politically motivated. Most likely, if I escape, I will be put on an international wanted list and deported. And I'm already under house arrest. I think, given the good chances given by the lawyers, it is better to stay here and try to solve the problem.

@o-m, About contracts. There are cases of pressure in some prisons, it's true. But the practice is that the prisoners themselves agree to go to war. Now it is possible to sign a contract even during the investigation, before the transfer to the court. As I was told, almost everyone agrees. They don't need much pressure. It is much more likely that you will end up in a torture camp, where you will be forced under torture to incriminate yourself so that you can be used to close an unsolved case. That is a much worse fate, in my opinion.

@gábor, I think you're right.

I think it would be helpful to discuss some specific countries. For example I found this article that talks about the US: https://scholarship.law.nd.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4942&context=ndlr
